# Recycler View (with adapter) doesnt show my items

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I use recycler view with adapter. I watched a tutorial on youtube and i did everything true. Just i used grid layout and card view (item row) for adapter as difference but adapter doesnt show items. I dont get an error. Everything looks fine. Where is my mistake? Is there anything incorrect in my code below?

My RecyclerView Fragment

```
package com.ahmetkaan.kediy

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager
import com.ahmetkaan.kediy.Adapter.Adapter
import com.ahmetkaan.kediy.data.NotlarViewModel
import com.ahmetkaan.kediy.databinding.FragmentNotlarBinding

class Notlar : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentNotlarBinding
    private lateinit var mNotlarViewModel : NotlarViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentNotlarBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        binding.recyclerView.adapter = Adapter()
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)

        mNotlarViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotlarViewModel::class.java)
        mNotlarViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { notlar ->
            Adapter().setData(notlar)
        })


        binding.notOlustur.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_notlar_to_notOlustur)
        }

        binding.kategoriler.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_notlar_to_kategoriler)
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

My Adapter

```
package com.ahmetkaan.kediy.Adapter

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.ahmetkaan.kediy.data.Notlar
import com.ahmetkaan.kediy.R

class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var notlarList = emptyList<Notlar>()

    class MyViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_notlar, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return notlarList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = notlarList[position]
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.titleC).text = currentItem.noteTitle
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.theNotC).text = currentItem.note
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dateTimeC).text = currentItem.dateTime
    }

    fun setData(notlar: List<Notlar>) {
        this.notlarList = notlar
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

My Item File (XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/categoriesButtonColor"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backgroundC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Başlık"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/backgroundC"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/theNotC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Not"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleC"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTimeC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="X/X/X"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/theNotC"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:src="@color/transparent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dateTimeC"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in your observer:

```
    mNotlarViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { notlar ->
        Adapter().setData(notlar)
    })
```

You are creating a brand new adapter by calling the adapter constructor with `Adapter()`. This new adapter is completely new and distinct from the one you already set on your RecyclerView, so passing data to it accomplishes nothing.

Assuming this is the only adapter you'll be using with this RecyclerView, you can get the existing one and cast it like this:

```
mNotlarViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { notlar ->
    (binding.recyclerView.adapter as Adapter).setData(notlar)
})
```

There could be other issues beyond this. That's just what jumped out at me.